# Why is the JavaScript NodeList immutable?

Tags: javascript, nodelist

Recently I came across the fact that the childNodes property of an element returns a NodeList and not an Array. Now I understand that a NodeList is meant to be a live collection of elements, but I don't get why that precludes it having methods like indexOf, or even push.

Could anyone explain why the only thing you can do with a NodeList is index it?

Comment: An indexOf method would be handy, but you can't use any kind of mutation because the NodeList might be a collection of elements from all over the DOM. Consider a collection of P elements returned by `getElementsByTagName` that might be in various parts of the DOM and not even be siblings - where would a "pushed" P be added? There are DOM methods for modifying the DOM, NodeLists are just a convenient way of keeping references to groups of them by name, tagName, class and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's the way it's specified. The DOM API was designed separately from JavaScript. The fact that `NodeList` has some common aspects with JavaScript arrays (`length` and indexing) is just...well, it's probably not actually a *coincidence*, but a by-product of inputs into the design process. Remember that JavaScript is not the only language that has DOM bindings.

You can readily affect the contents of a `NodeList` using the DOM API:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)

...or of course, your favorite JavaScript library.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that this was the case so that you'd have to use the proper DOM mechanisms for altering DOM structures.

Looking at it's compatibility problems, it's probably safer to use DOM methods anyway:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/NodeList

Comment: Also, it ensures that when you have a nodeList, you *know* its a representation of the state of the DOM at that point, and you don't have to worry about states.